# Can I play a Polish boxed edition of rocksmith on my english (uk) xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360, rocksmith-2014

I bought a copy of Rock Smith 2014 from an ebay auction which claimed to be an English copy.

I live in England (Uk)

I received the item today and the box art is in polish.

Is this going to be a problem or is it just box art?

Comment: Is it a sealed product? Can you test it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't be a problem since both countries use the PAL version of games.  The in-game language might be an issue, but there might be an option in the game to change that.  If you can find it.

Comment: I checked with the guy I bought it from and he was fine with my checking it out just in case. All menus and videos that I saw were in english. Unfortunately I over tightened and snapped a string during tuning. Now I have to wait 'til I can get another one tomorrow before playing :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no PAL / NTSC-US / NTSC-JAP restriction anymore, the only thing you need to check is if your language is available.
Either on wikipedia or online gaming database which is unfortunately in german, but easy to understand. on the left you can search by title.

http://ogdb.eu/index.php?section=title&titleid=27302